# Micro SD is not getting detected in PC only

Tags: windows, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, sd-card, card-reader

I've SanDisk Micro SD class 10 of 16GB.I've formatted and installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04.1 LTS for Raspberry Pi 2 and 3 systems (iso image) using Rufus like follows from windows10.

[image]

Due to some limitations of this raspberry pi version I decided to format this and install another version.

But when I insert micro sd card (through card reader) into my pc it's not getting detected. I double checked my card reader, I tested this by inserting another micro SD card into it. It's working.

The micro SD card is being detected by my android phone. So I cleared the contents of it and tested it again in windows PC. Still having the same issue. It's also not getting detected in Linux too. It's not being found in windows device manager, But displayed under Device Manager >> Disk drivers as shown below.

[image]

Any suggestions what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD card reader need to be able to understand the protocol that your SD card uses, newer SD cards use newer protocols but old card readers do not get updated or are not fast enough to understand how the SD card is communicating.

The solution is to buy a new SD card reader.

There are several generations of protocol and the reader must be able to understand the protocols the card uses in order to be read. The early SD protocol for example was (in theory) limited to 2GB, so SDHC was brought out but you'd need a new reader or firmware upgrade for your reader to support them. From [Wikipedia: SDHC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDHC)

> SDHC host devices are required to accept older SD cards. However, older host devices do not recognize SDHC or SDXC memory cards, although some devices can do so through a firmware upgrade.

Comment: Unless there is a firmware update for your card reader then no, you will need to get a new one.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Finally I got the reason :)